# C# - Json.Decode - Non MVC - The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

Tags: c#, json, class-library

I understand there are a ton of solutions to Encoding a large JSON string from an MVC point of view, and returning this from a controller.

What I cannot find, is a situation where I am **decoding** a large JSON string to an object in a non-MVC class library.  I reach a certain size where I get the error:

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
>   JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength property

**This is using Json.Decode found in System.Web.Helpers**

Example:

Say I have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
     public string id {get;set;}
     public string name {get;set;}
}
```

And getting a rather **large** result from an external API request , I decode like so:

```
    var result = Json.Decode<MyClass[]>(reponse);
```

Now, I have the ability to limit the number of returned records from the API request, but this doesn't help to show all the results available.

I have looked at all the solution on Stackoverflow I could find in regards to this error, but they all seem to involve serialization in an MVC environment.

(One example: [Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config), tried all solutions)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: If you are able to limit and if paging is available, why not do it in batches.. like limit to accepted # / request or something and add it to a list?